# How to return result in series from R function?

Tags: r, function

I am writing a 'rank' function to manipulate data in a dataframe. To do other manipulations, I need to split it to separate dataframes by 'cluster' variable.

I did it like this so far

```
#hypothetical dataframe    
gene <- c('A','B','C', 'B', 'F', 'E', 'A', 'C')
rank <- c(0.9, -1, 2, 23, -0.9, 3, 4, 90)
cluster <- c('1','1','1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3')
gene.data <- data.frame(gene, rank, cluster)

rank <- function(df, geneSet){
  clusterName <- paste0("cluster",df$cluster)
  splitData <- split(df,clusterName)
  splitData <- lapply(splitData, function(x) { x["cluster"] <- NULL; x })
  })
  }
```

I want to add 'fgsea' function inside my rank function to apply it to all separate cluster dataframes at the same time. I tried this

```
return(sapply(names(splitData), function (x) {fgsea(pathways=geneSet, stats=splitData[[x]], nperm=1000)})
```

But it gives me types of variables, not a real result.
[image]

When I apply 'fgsea' outside of the 'rank' function on splitData$cluster1, it gives me an expected result

```
fgseaRes <- fgsea(pathways=pathways.hallmark, stats=ranksMU150PDXTcluster1, nperm=1000)
```

[image]

Resuming,
I want the 'rank' function to give me fgseaRes for each cluster dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your `rank` function as :

```
rank <- function(df, geneSet){
  clusterName <- paste0("cluster",df$cluster)
  df$cluster <- NULL
  splitData <- split(df,clusterName)
  result <- lapply(splitData, function(x) { 
    fgsea(pathways=geneSet, stats=x, nperm=1000)  
  })
  return(result)
}
```